# MySQL - Обновить таблицу, удалив дубликаты и объединив столбцы

Tags: mysql

прошу подсказать, ПЛИИИЗ!

Необходимо обновить таблицу - удалить дубликаты (уникальность по столбцу ART), предварительно объединив у дубликатов другие столбцы (Poh)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В любом случае это минимум два запроса. На обновление и на удаление. Указывайте точную версию сервера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так. Создайте новую таблицу, заполните ее по запросу

```
INSERT INTO
    new_table (id,art,poh)
SELECT
    min(t.id), t.art, group_concat(t.poh)
FROM
    old_table t 
group by t.art
```

Удалите старую таблицу, а новую переименуйте

Comment: Да, @Mike, спасибо, поправил

Comment: Работает, спасибо!